# Path not found error in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

I have been getting this error in Zend framework when i want to run the static content , The error is like

```
///Not Found

The requested URL /public/content/services was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8090///
```

This is occuring when I try to access `localhost:8090/content/services`

Please give me a solution , thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is in the Apache error logs?

Comment: Something is wrong in configuration :D I dont know you files structure, zend configuration apache configuration so can't guess what's wrong.

Comment: If you deleted the .htaccess from /public ... where did you put it? That functionality is required for ZF to run as a MVC application.

Comment: can you run the non static content ? If you can then you can see the public path, because the index.php is in it.

Comment: @Vytautas give me ur mail id , i'll forward you the directory structure

Comment: @akond -The Apache log says ,( File does not exist: /var/www/square/public/content)

Comment: @Lucian Depold -The home page is fine , but when i am giving the paths to it , its showing Error 404

Comment: @RockyFord I have created the .htaccess file again , but its still giving the error :(

Comment: you have to have some pictures on your page. try accessing them directly and take a look at the path...

Comment: @LucianDepold , if you can give your email id , i will mail you the errors and code in detail , please help :)

Comment: first & lastname with dot @ big search engine

Comment: my guess would be htaccess disabled or something wrong with it try access page like this: `localhost:8090/index.php/content/services` if this works then its definetly your .htaccess file

Comment: @Vytautas , that displayed a page of errors ,Please tell me how to solve this and what to change in the .htaccess file , i'll copy the .htaccess also 

///An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (index.php)....and so on ///

Comment: @Vytautas
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ /square/public/index.php [NC,L]

Comment: Can you update your question with more details? where your index.php ant .htaccess is? what is www root folder? is mod_rewrite enabled? and everything you can what could help to help you..

Comment: @Vytautas , this is the book i have been following , refer from pg.33 and tell if there are any errors in the process of creating the project (vmg.pp.ua/books/.../PHP/Zend_Framework_A_Beginner_Guide.pdf)

Comment: did not understood your update WWW root folder should be your public dir if you don't use vhost then set `DocumentRoot = "/var/www/square/public/"` in apache config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Replaced "AllowOverride None " with "AllowOverride FileInfo " in httpd.conf file  and it worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you create the route in your application.ini as specified on page 39 "Defining Custom Routes"

```
//this needs to be exact
resources.router.routes.static-content.route = /content/:page 
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.controller = static-content
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.action = display
```

without the route being defined correctly the static content will not work as suggested by this book.

i/f you are going to use this book "Zend Framework: A Beginner’s Guide" follow the code as close as you can until you understand it. ZF1 is not trivial to understand.

Don't change your .htaccess arbitrarily, keep it as close to stock as possible. It's ok to use it to set the environment and that's about it. Zf1 won't work correctly if the .htaccess is even a little incorrect.

```
//stock .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I noticed you are using Ubuntu... Make sure you have the correct permissions and ownership of the files in your document root. Ubuntu has some different default settings for file permissions.

The book also instructs you to establish a vhost for your site ( *page 13 "Define Virtual Host Settings"* ). Please execute this recommendation it will make your life easier as you learn this framework.

Comment: Thank you very much , but i noticed that the bootstrap.php is empty , wat should i do with it ? please tell me

Comment: I have done all the above steps you have mentioned above , but the program is still not executing .Please tell me if anything is left incomplete and 
Is there any active group  for dicussion  of  Zend framework in the Internet , please tell

Comment: I can't "tell" you... I know what the instructions in the book are and I know how I set up my systems. I don't know how your system is setup and may be different. I do know I dislike Ubuntu as a web server OS because of the way the file permissions work. Best bet, start from page one and do each step one at a time and test test test.

Comment: Is there any active group for dicussion of Zend framework in the Internet , please tell

Comment: yeah , i created the project using #zf create project....
But is notice is being shown when i type the above command
Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your VHOST, please see docs/README
Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created.

Comment: are you working through "Zend Framework: A Beginner’s Guide" ?

Comment: you may need to make some adjustments to how you create your apache config with newer versions of Ubuntu. this might help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: phpunit notice is just that "A notice". no big deal and will not effect function of project.

Comment: I have done php examples already on this server and they are perfectly working , but i am not able to understand why zend applications are giving errors

Comment: your application is giving errors because something has not been done correctly. There are actually very few things that could be wrong. Go back to where it worked and move forward from there. Or take the easy way out and install Zend Server CE, if you can break that you have talent.